# PLSQL - Consulta entre tabelas

Tags: banco-de-dados, pl-sql

Olá, gostaria de sugestões de como posso realizar uma consulta entre duas tabelas (Permissão_Pessoa e Pessoa), onde temos a tabela Pessoa (pessoa_id, nome), a tabela Permissões(permissao_id, descricao) e a tabela Permissão_Pessoa(permissão_pessoa_id, pessoa_id, permissao_id).

```
Permissão = {{1,'Administrativo'},{2,'Usuário'},{3,'Colaborador'}}

Pessoa = {{1,'João'},{2,'Mario'},{3,'Maria'}}

Pessoa_Permissão = {{1,1,1},{2,1,3},{3,1,2},{4,2,2},{5,3,3}}
```

Eu preciso que ao executar a consulta, seja retornado os usuários que não possuem a permissão de colaborador (3).

Desde já agradeço.

**Atualização**

Preciso que a consulta retorne o nome e o id da pessoa (pessoa_id, nome). Segue abaixo o status atual de minhas tentativas.

```
select p.pessoa_id, p.nome
from pessoa p
join pessoa_permissão pes on pes.pessoa_id = p.pessoa_id
where pes.permissao_id <> 3;
```

Comment: a princípio vc só precisaria consultar a tabela Pessoa_Permissao onde o Id da Permissao for diferente de 3... mas precisava saber o que vc espera de saída da consulta (tem que trazer o nome da pessoa e a descricao da permissao?) e se possível nos mostre o que vc já tentou fazer

Comment: Certo, vou editar a pergunta. Agradeço pelo seu feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você estava no caminho, mas a sua consulta trazia todas as permissões da pessoa, menos a 3, o que não quer dizer que a permissão não exista... E se existisse você estava removendo ela da consulta.

Neste caso, utilize o operador (NOT) EXIST

```
SELECT
  p.pessoa_id,
  p.nome
FROM pessoa p
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM pessoa_permissao pp
  WHERE pp.pessoa_id    = p.pessoa_id
    AND pp.permissao_id = 3
)
```

Comment: Exatamente isso que eu estava tentando realizar, obrigado!

Comment: realmente, eu já estava quase dizendo que estava correta a consulta, mas ia trazer usuários que tem a permissão 3 (mas pode ter outra permissão)... boa @Kaue

Comment: @JMSlasher Obrigado pelo apoio!